# twython - No module named twython error

Tags: python, twython, raspberry-pi2

I installed tywthon on my raspberry pi using the following command:

```
sudo pip install twython
```

There were no errors during the install. When I run my python file it comes up with:

```
ImportError: No module named twython
```

Code is as follows:

```
import sys
import datetime
from twython import Twython

#Twitter keys

CONSUMER_KEY="xxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET ="xxx"
ACCESS_KEY = "xxx"
ACCESS_SECRET ="xxx"

api = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)

dt=datetime.datetime.now()
mon=4-dt.month
day=18-dt.day
hr=23-dt.hour
mn=60-dt.minute
sec=60-dt.second

pythonTest("Hi, I'm using my raspberry pi and python to tweet status     updates.")
python_string=("Time until Ben's birthday: "+str(mon)+" Months, "+str(day)+" days, "+str(hr)+" hours, "+str(mn)+" minutes")

api.update_status(status=python_Test)
```

I am using python 3. Not sure if that matters or not?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip3 install twython`? If you have 2.x installed, `pip` will install modules for 2.x by default.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, I think that is the issue. Python 2 is installed, but when I type that line of code you mentioned into terminal I get "pip3: command not found"

Comment: try installing python3-pip. If on a debian based system (eg Raspbian) try `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: @Trengot I've done that, the line `sudo pip3 install twython` still coming up with the `pip3: command not found` issue

Comment: OK, I've fixed it now.  Thanks for you help. The line I needed was `sudo pip-3.2 install twython`